# Display thumbnails before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, thumbnails

I am very unexperienced in Javascript/Jquery therefore I use the [JavaScript Load Image plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image) to handle the front end of my image upload process.

---

#### The Problem :

I would like to :

1. **upload multiple images**, not just one, and therefore also would like to
2. **display all the images, which are to be uploaded as a thumbnail in the results div**.

At the moment the thumbnails are appended to the end.

---

#### The Fiddle :

[**THE FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/r7s3n64b/7/)

---

#### The HTML (the relevant parts) :

```
<!-- FILE INPUT -->
<p><input type="file" name="images[]" id="upload-post-images" multiple></p>

<!-- THUMBNAILS -->
<div id="result" class="result">
    <p>Here the thumbnails should be displayed.</p>
</div>
```

---

#### My attempt to loop through the to be uploaded images :

```
// Call the plugin
document.getElementById('upload-post-images').onchange = function (e) {
    for(i = 0; i<=e.target.files.length; i++) {
       loadImage(
          e.target.files[i],
          function (img) {
              document.body.appendChild(img);
          },
          {maxWidth: 200} // Options
       );
    }
};
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!!

Comment: There is another example for jQuery image upload which has this feature working: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Thank you. But I don't use the JQuery File Upload Plugin. I use the JavaScript-Load-Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's appending to the end, because that's exactly what you're telling it to do here:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

That's appending the image to the body - that is, adding it to the end.

What you want to be doing is appending it to your target div.  You can find the div with the [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function, and then append the image to *that*:

```
document.querySelector('#result').appendChild(img)
```

Where '#' means 'has an id of', and '.' means 'has a class of', for instance.  If you were running this code with jQuery loaded, you could use the $() or [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) function instead, but your code is outside of the `$(function(){})` block, so it will run before jQuery has loaded.

The `$(function(){})` is just [shorthand](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) for `$(document).ready(function(){})`, which runs the enclosed function when the document has loaded (and thus loaded jQuery).

Comment: Thank you so much! That already helped me a lot. Now it does exactly what I want but it loops just the first image.

Comment: Sorry, I can't hold your hand from here on out.  You would do well to walk through your code and try to understand what each line does - perhaps even step through it with a debugger.  The [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is my goto reference for Javascript.